# stacked plot in ggplot2 based on dataset with frequency

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame as below, and I want to make a percentage stacked plot with ggplot 2 for it. Whatever tutorial I'm finding is based on having a column with different factors and then the factors are counted for finding their frequency. I already have the frequencies, is there a way I can make a percentage stacked plot for it?
My data frame is:

```
        NCWs    CWs
Fib 1   5918    4358
Fib 2   1609    2553
```

Comment: Not really relevant to your query, but I personally have a strong distaste for stacked barplots, namely cuz they can easily lead to misinterpretations (commonly when two stacked percentages are in one bar and people confuse the top bar as the cumulative percentage rather than the by-group percentage). I would personally recommend a dodged bar plot instead if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to wrangle your data into a format that `ggplot2` likes. In your case, you need to `pivot_longer()` using the `tidyr` package. To plot as percentages, in `ggplot()` use a combination of `position = "fill"` and `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)` for the labels.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(fib = c("fib 1", "fib 2"),
                 NCWs = c(5918, 1609),
                 CWs = c(4358, 2553))

# Create long format version of your data
df1 <- pivot_longer(df, -fib,
                    names_to = "VarName",
                    values_to = "Values")
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = df1,
           aes(x = fib, y = Values, fill = VarName),
           stat = "identity",
           position = "fill",
           width = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]